# Specify the same version for multiple dependency?

Tags: maven

Normally, when we want to specify the same version for multiple dependency
with properties. But we still have to add `<version>` element for every dependency. Is there any alternative way to this without `<version>` for every dependency?
Thank you!

```
   <properties>
    <springVersion>5.0.2</springVersion>
   </properties>    
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${springVersion}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Teams (also other libraries using that) uses a feature called [Bill Of Material (BOM) of Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) which makes it very convinient:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>import</cope>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Afterwards you can use a dependency simmply like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: It is very helpful! Thank you very!